# Is "sich wie ein Schneekönig freuen" -- "as happy as a wren" commonly used?

Tags: word-usage, archaism

This phrase appears in the [DWDS entry for *freuen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/freuen). It refers to a fable, repeated in both the [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wren#Etymology_and_usage) and [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaunk%C3%B6nig) Wikipedias, where the wren becomes king of the birds. Is the phrase still used now or is it the kind of thing you only hear in fairy tales?

Comment: It is still in use. See also [here](https://gfds.de/sich-freuen-wie-ein-schneekoenig/) or [here](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sich_freuen_wie_ein_Schneek%C3%B6nig).

Comment: it is still used today, but I would say it is used less

Comment: @Paul Frost Yes, I see it mentioned in several dictionaries and people teaching German on YouTube, but is it actually used, like in a recent novel or TV show? The one doesn't always imply the other.

Comment: Actually, I've found some uses now from [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=untertitel&q=Schneek%C3%B6nig). I should have checked there before asking.

Comment: The "official" German name for the wren is *Zaunkönig*. With that name it appears in the Brothers' Grimm fairy tail "Der Zaunkönig". This goes of course back to Aesop's Fable about the wren outwitting the eagle to become king of the birds. I doubt that there is connection between the fairy tail and the above phrase. Probabyl the phrase is based on the wren's behavior - it seems to enjoy life even in winter. I moreover guess that nowadays not too  many people are aware that "Schneekönig" is a synonym for "Zaunkönig". Perhaps they do not even have the idea that it is a bird.

Comment: And maybe future generations will not even know what "Schnee" is.

Comment: @PaulFrost: "Perhaps they do not even have the idea that it is a bird." - actually, I was just about to post a comment related to this ... indeed I never had the idea that "Schneekönig" could be a bird; my mental image for "sich freuen wie ein Schneekönig" was always that of a jolly fantasy creature that lives in the snow and rules there, for whatever reason. Or, maybe in a more mundane interpretation, that of a happy little child playing in and crafting stuff with the snow and thereby, so to speak, being "a king of snow".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper In fact, when I was a child, I had a similar idea as you. I can't remember when I learnt that it actually is a bird. This shows that our ancestors lived in a "different world" than we do. For most modern people, nature is no longer an essential part of their life, and even if they know the official word "Zaunkönig" and understand that it is a bird, they probably have never seen one or could identity it when they see one. I added my comment to my answer because it seems to be not completely irrelevant in the context of the question.

Comment: @Paul Frost -- If the phrase is indeed based on the bird's behavior or song, then the analogous phrase in English is "happy as a lark". There's also "on a lark" and "larking around". But apparently the origin of these may have nothing to do with the lark bird. In any case, imo their use today would be regarded as quaint at best.

Comment: I've never heard this phrase, so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does not only oocur in dictionaries etc., it is really used in everyday German. It does not prove anything if I tell you that I use it at suitable opportunity and that I also hear it not so seldom. But look at

[Example 1](https://www.procontra-online.de/artikel/date/2020/10/elefantenrunde-wie-kommen-die-versicherer-durch-die-krise/)

> "Wir würden uns wie ein Schneekönig freuen, wenn wir mit einer Null aus der Krise kommen", erklärte Patrick Dahmen, Vorstandsvorsitzender der HDI Lebensversicherungs AG.

[Example 2](https://www.snowplaza.de/weblog/51256-test-wie-wintersportverruckt-sind-sie/)

> Oder diejenigen, die sich bei jeder gesichteten Flocke auf den Webcams schon wie ein Schneekönig freuen.

[Example 3](http://www.ttv-gsw.de/component/content/frontpage/frontpage?start=145)

> Und wenn eine Veranstaltung reibungslos abläuft und auch noch gute Einnahmen in die Vereinskasse spült, kann ich mich immer wieder selbstlos wie ein Schneekönig freuen.

[Example 4](https://www.transfermarkt.com/ich-bin-rb-leipzig-fan-weil-vorstellungsthread-/thread/forum/477/thread_id/7/page/41)

> Würde mich wie ein Schneekönig freuen, wenn der nächste "Nicht-FC Bayern-Meister" eben RB Leipzig und nicht der BVB wird.

[Example 5](https://www.bergfex.at/sommer/mellau/gasthof-taube/?page=detail)

> Wie ein Schneekönig freuen können Sie sich winters im gemütlichen Haus mit Saunaanlage.

Also look at [this](https://schneekoenige.org/faqs/).

**Remark:**

The "official" German name for the wren is *Zaunkönig*. With that name it appears in the Brothers' Grimm fairy tail "Der Zaunkönig". This goes of course back to Aesop's Fable about the wren outwitting the eagle to become king of the birds. I doubt that there is connection between the fairy tail and the above phrase. Probably the phrase is based on the wren's behavior - it seems to enjoy life even in winter. I moreover guess that nowadays not too many people are aware that "Schneekönig" is a synonym for "Zaunkönig". Perhaps they do not even have the idea that it is a bird.

Comment: Thanks. It's hard to tell from a dictionary whether to spend time learning this kind of thing; sometimes it's an everyday expression you should have in active vocabulary and sometimes it's just a time waster since you'll never hear it used in real life. This one is very cute and charming, and the wren fable is now stuck in my brain anyway, but I'm trying to work out how much time I should put into keeping there long-term.

Comment: Additional remark: I have the feeling it's often used with a slight touch of irony, at least when used by younger people. But maybe that's true for most idioms. And in fact, it's used surprisingly often.

Comment: Yeah, that phrase is always used with a smirk ;-)

Comment: @RDBury My feeling is that it's rarely worth it to memorize sayings like this while you are still actively studying vocabulary. Even comparatively common ones really aren't *that* common (i.e., not stuff you will hear every day), and more often than not you'll figure out from context what it means. And if a saying is more common in your circles (i.e., because a German friends likes and uses it) you'll remember it automatically anyway.